# How Do You Horizontally Center the Contents in a Google Apps Script Flextable?

Tags: google-apps-script, centering, flextable

I am building my very first Google Scripts Web App.

I am using a FlexTable in a Google Apps Script to display my content.

I have been merrily using the following to set a variety of CSS styles for my content in the cells:

```
FlexTable.setStyleAttributes(row,col,{attribute: "value"});
```

However, it does not seem to respond to marginLeft nor marginRight at all.  How can I center the contents of a FlexTable cell?

Thank you for your kind consideration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, I have the answer.  I *was* successfully aligning the text within the cell.  However, it *appeared* that I was not because the CaptionPanel was left-justifying my FlexTable.

Note: I figured this out by assigning a high contrast background color to the FlexTable cell.

My solution (perhaps just a workaround) was to use setWidth to make the FlexTable cell fill the width of the CaptionPanel.

Thank you, Sam, for the conversation.  Your feedback helped me sort out the issue by helping build confidence that what I was doing with the FlexTable was correct.

Answer (score 0):

The code below works for text in flextable cells.

```js
//center for row
flexTable.setRowStyleAttribute(0, 'textAlign', 'center');

//for cell
flexTable.setText(0, 0, "Some Text").setStyleAttribute(0, 0, 'textAlign', 'center');
```

Comment: Sam, thank you for the reply.

There should be no difference if I am setting it alone or in a group, but I went ahead and replaced my code with your and it still does not center.

I *expect* that to work, but it does not.  I am looking at it in both Chrome and Firefox.

The funny part of this is that this is the simplest table I am creating in this app.  It only has one cell. :-(

Thank you again for trying to help me.

Comment: I am passing it a number value from an array, i.e.,

    flexTable.setText(0, 0, sheet[1][0]).setStyleAttribute(0, 0, 'textAlign', 'center');

and the value in sheet[1][0] is a number, not a string.

I would assume that is not a problem, but could that be a problem?  Sorry, I am not sure how to get this comment to render my code as code...

Comment: Convert the number to a string and you should be golden:

`var numAsString = sheet[1][0].toString();
flexTable.setText(0, 0, numAsString).setStyleAttribute(0, 0, 'textAlign', 'center');`

Comment: Sam, I tried that, even using your exact code, but it still did not center... :-(

Comment: Not sure what your issue could be in that case. Without seeing the rest of your code it would very hard to offer any further advice. The only thing I can suggest would be adding your flexTable to a panel of some kind before adding it to the UiApp, if you're not already.

Comment: Sam, I flipped on the background color for the table and it appears that the problem may be the CaptionPanel is not centering the FlexTable.  Basically, the text is centered, but it is a single cell and when I call it in the CaptionPanel, it is left-justified in the panel.